# RSpec/Capybara: Strange behaviour doesn't find <input type="hidden">, but it definitely is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have the following spec:

```
within dom_id_selector(@boilerplate_copy) do
  within '.copied_attributes_differing_from_original' do
    within 'form.title[action="http://www.textdiff.com/"]' do
      expect(page).to have_css 'button', text: 'Title'
      expect(page).to have_css 'input[name="string1"]'
      expect(page).to have_css 'input[name="string2"]'
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the HTML in question:

```
<div class="copied_attributes_differing_from_original">
  <form action="http://www.textdiff.com/" class="title" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input name="string1" type="hidden" value="Boilerplate Original test title">
    <input name="string2" type="hidden" value="Boilerplate Copy test title">
    <button type="submit">Title</button>
  </form>

  <form action="http://www.textdiff.com/" class="success_criterion_id" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input name="string1" type="hidden">
    <input name="string2" type="hidden" value="1">
    <button type="submit">Success criterion</button>
  </form>

  // More of them...
  <form action="http://www.textdiff.com/"...
</div>
```

While the first `have_css` passes (the button is found), the second `have_css` fails:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css 'input[name="string1"]'
   expected to find css "input[name=\"string1\"]" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

But in my opinion this element definitely is there! I also don't understand the output `Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.`, what does it mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Capybara doesn't find non-visible elements (which hidden inputs are) because a user can't see/interact with them.  If you really need to check the presence of a non-visible element you can do

```
expect(page).to have_css('input[name="string1"]', visible: false)
```

That being said, since feature tests should be testing that the page functionality works rather than the details of exactly how it works you may not want to check for the presence of hidden inputs but rather just make sure the functionality they implement works.

Comment: Ah, thank you! You're right, feature tests should be black-box, but I'm testing that a form exists that sends data to an external resource (which is out of my test scope), so the only thing I can do is to make sure the data is available as expected.

Comment: Do you have an idea what `Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.` should mean?

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim the only finding visible behavior  is implemented as a filter on the capybara results, so it's telling you it found an element that matched the CSS selector, but didn't match the visibility filter

Comment: I understand what it means, but I think it's a pretty confusing message. ;)